# Which type to use for callable to std::bind

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, bind

in a function I need to pass as argument a callable for std::bind.
What is the correct type/template I should use?

```
void foo(std::function<void(KnownType)> function, WhatShouldThisBe target)
{
    std::bind(function, target);
}
```

The intended use would then be:

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeType> bar = std::make_shared<SomeType>();
foo(&SomeType::function, bar);
```

Comment: function with signature `void()` does not take arguments. typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
template <class T>
void foo(std::function<void(KnownType)> function, T&& target)
{
    std::bind(function, std::forward<T>(target));
}
```

Comment: thx, but is there a way to not specify the type T when calling foo?(similar to the way std::bind does not need to know the specific type?)

Comment: Compiler should deduce it so you should be able to call it as `foo(function, arg)`